# How to display the default table of elements given in angular through the schematic ng generate @angular/material:material-table

Tags: angular

**Edit: I managed to get how to do it!**

So, I have an angular project. I used the schematic given below to generate a new component for my project.

```
ng generate @angular/material:material table --name data-table
```

It generated the component successfully. However, when I run my angular project on localhost:4200, I just end up with a blank page (my app.component.html file is empty). What do I have to add in my angular files to display the default table given through the schematic (view https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview).

I have the following files for my angular project-- app-routing.module.ts, app.component.ts, app.component.css, app.component.html, app.component.spec.ts, app.module.ts, data-table-datasource.ts, data-table.component.css, data-table.component.html, data-table.component.spec.ts and data-table.component.ts.

The data table given in data-table-datasource.ts is an array with the id and the elements names:

```
const EXAMPLE_DATA: DataTableItem[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Helium'},
```

all the way up to

```
  {id: 20, name: 'Calcium'},
];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the  link [https://v6.material.angular.io/guide/schematics][1]  for  installing angular material (ng add @angular/material) if it helps you.